# Apache timeouts when 2 users with same IP

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7

We have 2 servers both running centos7 and apache 2.4 that are used for completely internal use only. The problem when 2 people in the office with of course the same IP try to use the server via their browser (viewing reports, testing code, ect.) apache will randomly timeout their browser.

Both have a completely stock install of apache 2.4 on them done simply via:

```
yum install httpd
```

PHP is also installed with but I have also tried removing PHP with the same results so it seems isolated to apache.

Both servers are completely up to date patch wise and I am not sure what else to try to find out what is going on.

I should also mention that, the servers are not in the office, rather at a outside hosting facility.

Anyone with any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: How is it that two people have the same IP address?

Comment: In same office, I should of mentioned server is not in the office in out side hosting facility.

Comment: @jrodichok, what do you mean when they are accessed using the same ip? both the servers are behind same ip or the client pc's accessing them have same ip?

Comment: @bangal Clients's PC's are on the same IP.

Comment: @jrodichok, the problem is definitely not with the server but with the clients. Fix your LAN and the problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had the same problem (but not limited to any particular web server, it even happened when accessing ssh).  Our issue was the following setting in our `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
```

This was being set for us as part of a server "optimization" script we were testing.  As you can read [here](http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2014-tcp-time-wait-state-linux.html), this value should never be used because of problems with NAT.

Hope this helps you or someone else!